# How can I connect A java file with B java file

Tags: java, mouseevent, mouselistener

I'm developing a point of sales program and made 2 separate java files. I wanted to make like this

If I click T1 Button
Move to the cash register system page and bring the table number and show Tasting Room(T1)
Hit some menu buttons according to customers order
Save their order list
Hit the Go back button

and circle this functions.

1.How can I move the table arrangement java file with the cash register file and get the table number or the opposite when someone hit the Table button or Go back button?
2.To save the order lists, what function can I use?

Thanks :)!
[image: Table Page]
[image: Cash Register Page]

Answer (score 1):

You can use serialization, which means saving the state of an object to a file then using this file to re-create instances of the same type.

```
public class Employee implements java.io.Serializable
{
   public String name;
   public String address;
   public transient int SSN;
   public int number;

   public void mailCheck()
   {
      System.out.println("Mailing a check to " + name + " " + address);
   }
}
```

taking the employee class as an example, we need to create one employee instance normally with the new operator, set some properties.

```
public class JavaApplication40 {

        static Employee master;
        static Employee copy;

        public static void main(String[] args) {

            master = new Employee();
            master.name = "Reyan Ali";
            master.address = "Phokka Kuan, Ambehta Peer";
            master.SSN = 11122333;
            master.number = 101;

            serialize();
            deserializing();
        }
```

the last two methods will do the trick for you.

```
public static void serialize ()
{


    try{
        FileOutputStream fileOut =  new FileOutputStream("c:\\master.ser");
        ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(fileOut);
        out.writeObject(master);
        out.close();
        fileOut.close();
        System.out.printf("Serialized data is saved in /tmp/master.ser");
    }catch(IOException i){
        i.printStackTrace();
    }
}


public static void deserializing ()
{

  try{
     FileInputStream fileIn = new FileInputStream("c:\\master.ser");
     ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(fileIn);
     copy = (Employee) in.readObject();
     in.close();
     fileIn.close();
  }catch(IOException i){
     i.printStackTrace();
     return;
  }catch(ClassNotFoundException c){
     System.out.println("Employee class not found");
     c.printStackTrace();
     return;
  }

  System.out.println("Deserialized Employee...");
  System.out.println("Name: " + copy.name);
  System.out.println("Address: " + copy.address);
  System.out.println("SSN: " + copy.SSN);
  System.out.println("Number: " + copy.number);
}
```

this will result in saving the state of the master object to the file system
and then creating the copy object using the same data that is saved in the file.

hope this helps you.

Comment: note that the Employee class must implement java.io.Serializable

Comment: also any variable in this class will be written to the file. unless you declare it as transiet.

Comment: transient String userPassword;